# How to deploy files into a device for multi-app access

Tags: android, file, android-sharing

My idea is to develop an application for Android, which is able to do the following:

The APK-File contains a resource, e.g. a pdf-file. And this file should be accessible for certain other apps. My intention is to install that /res/raw/-file in a dedicated Directory, e.g. /Download/PDF-Files, where it can be accessed by different applications.

This process should be done by installation of the app.

How should I configure the manifest.xml for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

During the installation process, no action can be performed unless the user presses 'open' to launch the app. The code that first executes after that is the onCreate() method of your MainActivity specified in your manifest. To do that you have to add the code in the onCreate() method. You also need to add the following permission:

Comment: If I understand you correcty...It is not possible to create an app, which only purpose is to deploy ressources without user interaction